# How to find tags From a string

Tags: php, string, tags, blogs

i am writing a blog script .

i want to find tags from the article ..

what is the best way to find tags from the body string in php

Example :
if an article body contains this string

'This Question is about php strings'

so the script should get `php` `string` and `Question` as tag .

Comment: `explode` by space and check every word against the list?

Comment: you mean i have to use a list of words ?

Comment: Look into a [**DOM Parser**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: how else would the script know which words are tags? In your example, why are `this`, `is` and `about` not considered tags? The only reason you don't consider them tags is that in your head, you have a list of words that you consider common. So you would either need to make a list of common words and exclude those or create a list of un-common words and match to consider those all tags.

Comment: Also, don't forget about variations on words. Would the word `string` be tagged as well? You have `strings`. So would you create a list of words and all possible variations? You could. You could also create a gramatical lexer that uses proper grammer to find variations on words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, but one of them could be to use `strpos`:

```
$mystring = 'This Question is about php strings';

$wordsToFind = array('php','strings','Question');

foreach ($wordsToFind as $word)
    if (strpos($mystring, $word)) {
        echo $word.' has been found'; echo "\n";
    }
```

You can **[try it out here](http://3v4l.org/VZPOF)**

Comment: `stripos` would probably be better so case isn't taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the tags first. Then then a script will find the any one of it is present in the article and add the tags in another array() and that will be the tags for that particular article.

```
$defined_tags = array('php', 'string', 'questions', 'javascript', 'python');
$article_tags = array();
$string = "This Question is about php strings";

foreach($defined_tags as $tag)
{
    if (strpos($string,$tag) !== false) 
    {
        $article_tags[] = $tag;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Good.. i was writing a snippet to answer my own question .. but did it .. thanks